# Python - Read file and adjust output (do not understand error)

Tags: python, python-2.7

My goal is to write a program which has this file as input:

```
Anne Adema____________6.5 5.5 4.5 
Bea de Bruin__________6.7 7.2 7.7
Chris Cohen___________6.8 7.8 7.3 
Dirk Dirksen__________1.0 5.0 7.7
```

And gives this as output:

```
Report for group 2b
Anne Adema has an average grade of 5.5
Bea de Bruin has an average grade of 7.2 
Chris Cohen has an average grade of 7.3
Dirk Dirksen has an average grade of 4.6 End of report
```

This is what I have made but it doesn't work and I do not fully understand why. I think splitting the names from the grades is going wrong but I do not know how to solve that.

```
import sys

def print_grade(input_grades):
    grades = input_grades.split()
    grade1 = float(grades[0])
    grade2 = float(grades[1])
    grade3 = float(grades[2])

    final_grade = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3) / 3
    print "%.2f." %final_grade

def print_names(student) :
    input_list = student.split("_+")
    full_name = input_list[0]
    final_grade = input_list[1]

    print "%s has an average grade of " % names
    print_grade(final_grade)

students = open('input.txt').readlines()

print "Report for group 2b"

for student in students:
    print_names(student)

print "End of report"
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 25, in <module>
Report for group 2b
    print_names(student)
  File "...", line 15, in print_names
    final_grade = input_list[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Why shouldn't the result for Chris Cohen go on a line of its own?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. I'll edit it

Answer (score 1):

The split method of the string does not accept a regular expression. You should use [the one at re module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split):

```
re.split("_+", student)
```

besides that, the variable *name* does not exists, you should be using *full_name*:

```
print "%s has an average grade of " % full_name
```

In order to not print a new line, you should use a comma after the [print statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement):

```
print "%s has an average grade of " % full_name,
```

Answer (score 1):

`input_list = student.split("_+")`

`str.split()` does not recognize a regular expression. That would be parsed as the string `_+` and that doesn't match what you want to match.

There is no index == 1 here, `final_grade = input_list[1]` because in the line above that attempted to split the string didn't, so its all in `input_list[0]`.

Might want to import re and do that split using `re.split('_+', student)`.